# Replacing a value after comparing 2 columns from VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have to compare SYSIDs in 2 excel sheets and replace SYSID in first sheet with Component ID in 2nd sheet.

```
First sheet:                       Second Sheet:
SYSIDS                             SYSIDS  COMPONENT_ID
123                                 123      111
345                                 345      222
678                                 678      333
```

First sheet Output should be:

```
SYSIDs:
111
222
333
```

How can I get it done?

Comment: To do this in place will require vba.  You can have a second column on the first sheet that will use a simple VLOOKUP to reference the existing and output the result in the new column.  Is that what you want or do you want to make the changes in place?

Comment: You cannot _replace_ values with formula. The only way is set a column with `VLOOKUP`, then copy and paste with values only back to SYSIDS column. Otherwise, you should use a VBA marco.

Comment: Yes I can have a second column on the first sheet but want the Component_ids to be matching corresponding to the SYSIDs, can you help me with the VLOOKUP function output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: A2 and A:B represent?

Comment: They are cell references.

Comment: Thank You very much Scott, I got the required output! Cheers